# What could be the purpose of an output port without downstream

Tags: apache-nifi

I worked on a Nifi flow that contains output port without downstream, i looked on documentation and web but i can't figure what could be the purpose of such ports.

Does someone know ?

Could it act as a final node ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Input and output ports on the root canvas are for remote access by another NiFi instance to push or pull data. So an output port on the root canvas would allow another NiFi instance to pull data from it via an Remote Process Group on the other instance.

Previously any ports inside nested process groups were local ports used to bring data in and out of the process group, but in the latest release you can now right click on any port and configure it be remote.

Comment: And if an output port has no downstream it means that it is used by a remote process group ?

Comment: Probably, I mean the nifi instance where the output port is does not know about other nifi instances that might pull from it, so someone could just route data to an output port and will just build up in the queue if nothing connects to pull it